# Redirect custom URLs from one domain to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is this possible using htaccess?

I'm trying to redirect URLs like this:
onedomain.com/xyz --> anotherdomain.com/user/xyz

I've tried this but no luck:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\/?)$ http://anotherdomain.com/user/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

I make it in this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/user/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```